# ETH Denver 2022 - Kitties custom front-end repo link not available anymore

Tags: kitties, substrate-front-end

`git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/ --branch tutorials/kitties`

The above link is not available anymore. Would you mind sharing the right or latest version one?
TIA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the kitties solution branch for the front-end:

- https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/tree/tutorials/solutions/kitties

Answer (score 2):

i guess you can find all the branch by doing :

```
git branch -a  // to list all branch
```

and

```
git checkout name_of_branch //to change the current branch
```